# Build a Docker Linux Container with Jenkins including dynamically added password

Tags: docker, jenkins, passwords

I need to build a complex docker container which has an alpine Linux, sftp, vstp and a special application who relies on input from sftp|ftps from a list of customers.

However, this container acts more like a full blown VM...anyway I have to dynamically create the container including all user accounts with their passwords.

I managed it with a bash script, supervisord and a nice Dockerfile:
Result -> it works like a charm.

While I copy my script plus all the config files and app data etc. inside the container I also provide a classic csv list to add my users and their belonging group memberships and passwords.

So far so good...Ok, now the problem. The whole content should be stored in a git repo and absolute no passwords should be there...and:
- no git encryption
- no docker compose
- no docker services etc.

Now my task is to provide all passwords via environment variables through jenkins (not Dockerfile ENV's) ...I have no idea how I can do this. I mean...environment variables are in the environment from jenkins and not inside the container ? Any recommendations ?

Comment: Have you tried mounting volume with sources (folder which is going to be uploaded to git, sources with data for jenkins) from host to docker container?

Comment: Actually I use 2 volumes for the container (customer data and logs).
Perhaps I can keep the csv locally in a 3rd volume and import that file ? But this is still not what my boss wants regarding the environment vars.

Comment: Ok, it was simpel. Had to map the csv via the cli directly to the container. WORKS !!!